# Are there any unlimited Graffiti items in CS:GO?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I just returned to playing CS:GO after taking a long break, and I noticed a new type of item in the game: Graffiti ([blog](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/2016/10/16255/), [faq](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7737-UKVB-0657)). I'm a sucker for silly cosmetics in games so I was immediately interested until I saw that, unlike most other in-game items,

> When a player unseals graffiti they can apply that pattern 50 times.

the ones I saw were consumable/had a limited number of charges. I'm not so interested in that.

However, companies often release limited-edition or promotional versions of items that are better than the normal versions. In this case, I could imagine something like non-tradable Souvenir versions.

Does any type of non-limited graffiti item exist for CS:GO?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  At the moment all possible graffiti items, whether they be from drops or capsules, are capped at a limited amount of uses of 50.